# Date in js ? with setInterval?

Tags: javascript

Why does this need a refresh to work if there is a setInterval? the only thing I can think of is that it correctly writes the first iteration of the data(which it does) and then for some reason the .write function will not just write over it? I have seen a few examples on here and they are not too complicated in the sense that I cannot understand how to get them to work, they are too complicated in the sense that this is something that should easily be done with one line of code. Just looking to have the date display and update in real time in seconds.

```
<div id="date"><script>
            
            setInterval(document.write(Date()),1000)
            
            </script></div>
```

Comment: Maybe read up on what `document.write` does?

Comment: Yea it writes to the document, why will it not overwrite? It's annoying to have to getelement by id, clear everything in it, then .write to it.

Comment: The [HTML Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dynamic-markup-insertion.html#document.write()) specifically says that `document.write()` has "very idiosyncratic behavior.", and it's use is strongly discouraged.

Comment: setInterval first parameter needs to be a function.

Comment: If that be the case why is it even in the standard? Why not have it removed so browsers cannot compile it?

Comment: They're very conservative about making breaking changes. Also, document.write() does have valid uses, specifically when the page is first loading.

Comment: your conception of what html and javascript  only exists in your imagination, which is not reality.